# In MSVC, any way to see all #include files on an error

Tags: visual-c++

Suppose we have 'foo.cpp' includes 'bar.h' includes 'baz.h' includes 'grog.h', and 'grog.h' has an error in it. GCC will produce a message that says something like "error in file grog.h, included from baz.h:10, included from bar.h:5, included from foo.cpp:20."

Is there any way to make MSVC produce a similar message? Sometimes you only need to know the file itself, but it's not terribly infrequent that chasing up the #include chain is useful.

(You can turn on the /showIncludes option for a short time and see where it's included, but that produces a ton of output and it's not really reasonable to keep that on after the error is fixed.)

Answer (score 0):

Barring a more elegant solution from someone else, you could write an analyzer that parses your output file with /showIncludes turned on into something more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ in its later versions actually does a pretty good job of including context info when the error requires it - template errors point through the chain of includes back to the line of **your** code that actually caused the compiler error in `boost/horrifically_complex_mpl_code.hpp`, warnings about ambiguous overloads show all possible candidates, and so on.

I'm not aware of any way to do exactly what you want though.  You can generate full preprocessed source output using [/P](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) but that's not as single-shot convenient as the feature you describe.